# How to reseed db without duplication - Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-seeding

I have this seeder class in my laravel 5.2 app :

```
class UserTypesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
{

    DB::table('user_types')->insert([
[
    'type' => 'patient',
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
],
[
    'type' => 'doctor',
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
]
```

]);

```
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add another record in the same seeder class. I tried using firstOrCreate() :

```
UserType::firstOrCreate([
        'type' => 'patient',
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);
    UserType::firstOrCreate([
        'type' => 'doctor',
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);
    UserType::firstOrCreate([
        'type' => 'admin',
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);
```

but it made duplicate records and so did updateOrCreate().

So, how can I add new records to the same seeder class without duplicating records ??

Comment: reset the table and then seed?

Comment: can't delete records from the table as they are foreign keys in other tables. @HorusKol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `firstOrCreate` method is not working as expected because the time of the previous record is not same with the new query. So, if you remove the `created_at` and `updated_at` from your query as below:

`UserType::firstOrCreate([ 'type' => 'patient' ]);`

Now, it should work. Beside, `created_at` and `updated_at` will automatically be managed by `firstOrCreate` method.

Comment: Yes, it's working after deleting created_at and updated_at.
 Thanks a lot.